# EnumDropDownListFor localization resx value sort

Tags: razor, enumdropdownlistfor

I'm new to razor mvc and mvc in general.  I have an EnumDropDownListFor that displays Countries in the appropriate language. What I need to have is the dropdownlist sorted in alpha order depending on the different localization resx values.

in my cshtml I have:

```
<div>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Country)</div>
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Country)
```

I have an enum CountryModel.cs :

```
//[Display(Name = "None", ResourceType = typeof(Web.Models.CountryResources.Fixtures))]
    //None = 0,
    [Display(Name = "Canada", ResourceType = typeof(Web.Models.CountryResources.Fixtures))]
    Canada = 1,
    [Display(Name = "Mexico", ResourceType = typeof(Web.Models.CountryResources.Fixtures))]
    Mexico = 2,
    [Display(Name = "UnitedStates", ResourceType = typeof(Web.Models.CountryResources.Fixtures))]
    UnitedStates = 3
```

Values are stored in resx files for the different languages. For English this is displaying in the correct order based on order in countrymodel but for say French, it should be (values coming from country.fr.resx):
    Canada
    États Unis (which is United States)
    Mexique (which is Mexico)
instead of:
    Canada
    Mexique
    États Unis

My list actually has 37 countries and we could add to it at any time. The selected country's integer is written to the db for later retrieval/editing.

So how do I get the EnumDropDownListFor to sort based on resx values? Should I be using something other than the EnumDropdownListFor? I've seen examples for getting values from resx and have that working but I haven't found examples of making it sort appropriately based on those values.  Thank you!

Edit: forgot to say my Model has:

```
[Display(Name = nameof(Account.Account.Country), ResourceType = typeof(Account.Account))]
    public CountryModel Country { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up switching to a DropDownListFor instead and have it working. Not sure if there is a better way using the EnumDropDownListFor but I couldn't find it.

So, switched from:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Country)
```

to:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country, EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(Mlc.Acs.Web.Models.CountryModel)).OrderBy(x => x.Text))
```